# VARIABLE INDEFINIDA CHART

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hola muy buenas tardes tengo un problema de variable en mi clase `estadisticas.blade.php`, donde estoy utilizando `{!! $chart->html() !!}`, pero *laravel* me dice que no está definida; exactamente me dice esto:

> ( Undefined variable: chart)

mientras que en mi grafica controller le estoy dando un `compact`

Grafica controller:

[image: Grafica controller:]

web.php[image: web.php]
estadisticas.blade.php
[image: estadisticas.blade.php]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes por lo menos 2 `Route::get('/estadísticas' , ...)` y otra `Route::get('estadísticas' , ...)`. Creo que eso está confundiendo a Laravel y tal vez no sabe para donde rutear. Deja solo la que rutea al controlador `GraficaController`.